# Data interaction between ipad and server

Tags: ios, ipad, server, interaction

I am new in ipad developing and I need to develop an app that need to get data from server then display the data to the user.Can you give me some advice? If you show some examples or documents link, that's better.

Comment: 1st advice - start with reading some basic docs may be? + there's a lot of standard samples that apple provides which contain interactions with servers - why not see how the work?

Comment: Thanks for your advises. Because I haven't much time on this work, so I want to get some general methods first then try to see the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a starter for ten, the most common means of fetching data from a server are via the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)  `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` method (and other related methods in NSString) and the [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, which is capable of performing asynchronous background requests.

Both of the above linked class reference documents contain code samples (see the "Related sample code" section at the top of each).

Additionally, there are 3rd party solutions available, such as the commonly used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) class.

In terms of the displaying the fetched data, you really need a better idea of iOS programming to answer this yourself, as it's too large in scope to meaningfully answer. However, a good start would be the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) guide.